# permissions override inside Files

Tags: release-juno, pantheon-files, permissions

How to move files inside Juno/Pantheon "Files" if blocked by permissions?

I want to use the graphic interface tabs to drag things around, but I don't see an equivalent of "sudo mv…" for this action. Workaround is copy/paste "Files" paths into "Terminal" commands, which works okay. Similar blocks exist inside other graphic tools that create directory modifications, like unarchive, which I hope an answer may also apply to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> BAD IDEA WARNING!

I believe you will achieve the desired effect by running Files with sudo permissions. To do that, got to `Applications` -> right-click on `Files` -> `New Window as Administrator` -> input your password in the authentication window -> Files is running. You'll be able to move, edit and delete any file you want (EVEN THE CRITICALLY IMPORTANT ONES!)

Comment: Perfect. Not a bad idea, but exactly the feature I was hoping for. Was already using "sudo mv…" so little additional risk. Bonus lesson: didn't know dock item right-select was item-specific and dynamic.

Comment: There is an outstanding issue filed against Files for providing an way to temporarily elevate the users permissions without opening a new window as administrator from the dock.  See https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/165.  See also https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/224 and https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/363